# Willst du mich pizzen?

Tags: wordplay

Ich habe vor einem Restaurant eine Anzeige gesehen, in der "**Willst du mich pizzen?**" stand.

Nach dem Duden ist "pizzen" kein deutsches Verb. Die Bedeutung (dass diese Werbung um Pizza geht) ist mir trotzdem klar. Als Anglophone finde ich das lustig, weil eine der möglichen englischen Übersetzungen ist "Do you want **to pizza me**?" das ähnlich wie "Do you want **a piece of me**?" klingt. Letzteres ist eine umgangssprachliche Einladung zum Kampf.

Ich frage mich, ob es hier auf Deutsch ein ähnliches Wortspiel gibt, das ich einfach nicht verstehe? Oder denke ich einfach zu viel nach? ;-)

Comment: "Die Bedeutung ist mir trotzdem klar." - mir nicht. Könntest du bitte eine kurze Erläuterung einfügen? Ist das ggf. ein Euphemismus für "flachlegen" (also mit jemandem schlafen), weil eine Pizza auch flach ist? Oder soll die Bedeutung dem englischen Begriff entsprechen? Letztendlich scheint das kontextuell bei deinem Beispiel nicht passen (meine Hypothese freilich auch nicht).

Comment: *eine umgangssprachliche Einladung zum Kampf* - anpissen gibt es in der Deutschen Sprache :)

Comment: Ich schätze, es ist eine Übersetzung von _do you wanna pizza me_, der ursprüngliche Witz geht im Deutschen allerdings verloren.

Comment: @ORMapper Sorry: ich meinte nur, dass diese Anzeige eine Werbung für das Restaurant ist, und dass dieses Restaurant Pizza anbietet. (Es war ein Bild von einer Pizza dabei.) Ob es andere Bedeutungen oder Wortspiele gibt ist genau meine Frage.

Comment: In Musikerkreisen ist die Vokabel *pizzen* umgangssprachlich für *Pizzicato spielen* gebräuchlich. Mir fällt auch keine ähnliche Bildung bei anderen Nahrungsmitteln ein: *knödeln*, *gurken*, *semmeln* gibt es zwar, hat aber keinen erkennbaren Sinnzusammenhang. *Verwursten* ist ein anderes Wortbildungsmuster.

Comment: Ich weiß es auch nicht, würde aber jetzt gerne jemanden marzipankartoffeln.

Comment: Ich würde es als eine Einladung auf eine Pizza verstehen im Sinn von "Willst du mich einladen?" oder um beim Englischen zu bleiben "Willst du mich daten?" Viel Meta-Ebene sehe ich da aber auch nicht...

Comment: Es gibt keine Bedeutung. Die Wirkung besteht darin, dass man sich ungebührlich lange mit dem Satz beschäftigt. "Willst Du mich küssen? Willst Du mich f***?" ist die naheliegende Bildung - die Pizza ist wundervoll wie ein Kuss. Ob der Kunde drauf kommt ist  ungewiss. "Willst Du mich am Abend besuchen?" wäre die, auf die ein Pizzafeind vielleicht kommt. Für Nichtmuttersprachler: "Du kannst mich mal am Abend besuchen" ist geläufiige Abmilderung einer ähnlichen Formulierung, die nach dem großen A miit "rsch lecken" ungeschönt ihre Fortsetzung findet.

Comment: Ich finde den Werbespruch sehr originell und weiß sofort, was mit dieser kreativen Wortschöpfung gemeint ist. Mit einer englischen Übersetzung braucht man es dazu überhaupt gar nicht in Verbindung bringen.

Comment: @äüö: Ja *was denn*? 50% der Benutzer verstehen den Spruch offenbar auf Anhieb, wollen aber den anderen 50% nicht verraten, worum es geht :( Ok, ich finde den Spruch auch originell und im gegebenen Kontext verstehe ich ihn auch (es handelt sich offenbar um die Aussage einer personifizierten Pizza, die als ebensolche behandelt bzw. gegessen werden will), aber es wäre für andere Benutzer schon nützlich, gleich eine Erklärung hinzuzufügen.

Comment: @äüö: Ich verstehe den Witz ehrlich gesagt auch nicht. Wenn ihn du oder jemand sonst erklären kann, bitte tut es!
Was mir noch einfiele, wäre, wenn es in Köln oder im Rheinland war, eine Anspielung auf "bützen", aber dann müsste bei der Werbung zumindest ein Bild mit Bezug zum Karneval dabei sein, damit man es versteht.

Comment: @HalvarF: Die Pizza sagt einfach im Werbespruch zum Käufer "Komm iss mich!", aber nicht durch Verwendung des langweiligen Verbs "essen" sondern kreativ-witzig durch das neu (von der Werbefirma) erfundene Verb "pizzen", was übelst witzig rüberkommt... oder eben auch nicht, wie man hier sieht - LOL. Ist so ähnlich wie bei "unkaputtbar" (unzerstörbar), bei "harzen" (Hartz4), wo man Wörter aus anderen Wortarten witzig kreiert. Mehr steckt hier, glaube ich, gar nicht dahinter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ab und zu werden Substantive kreativ zu Verben gemacht, um salopp Dinge kurz und prägnant auszudrücken. Aus Pizza wird hier `pizzen` gemacht, um einfach einen witzigen, provokativen Effekt für den Werbespruch zu erzielen, der sich bei der Zielgruppe einprägt.

Ähnliches Verfahren findet man bei `harzen`, welches aus Hartz 4 entstand, `skypen` (aus Skype) usw., wobei es bei `pizzen` natürlich (gewünscht) überzogen ist.

Eine gewollte Analogie zu Phrasen im Englischen würde ich hier für eher spekulativ und unwahrscheinlich halten. Im Deutschen gibt es außer dem sprachlich verwendeten Prinzip kein direktes Wortspiel, auf das sich der Spruch bezieht.